# Plain Tex error using tikz and dvips

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex, dvips

Here is my Plain Tex file (example taken from the manual)

```
\input tikz.tex

\baselineskip=12pt

\hsize=6.3truein

\vsize=8.7truein

We are working on

\tikzpicture

\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);

\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);

\endtikzpicture.

\bye
```

Here it is the log, when I try to compile using tex (pdftex works fine)

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=tex 2020.10.11)  24 OCT 2020 22:32
**2020_10_19_tikz.tex
(./2020_10_19_tikz.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks12
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen16
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen17

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@IfUndefined #1->\ifcsname 
                                   #1\endcsname \expandafter \pgfutil@second...
l.849 \pgfutil@IfUndefined{directlua}
                                     {%
? X
No pages of output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifcsname` is an extended command not available in the original TeX, so use the command `etex` if you want dvi or `pdftex` if you want PDF.

The start of the terminal output should look like

```
$ etex file
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=etex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./file.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex
```

Note the **entering extended mode**

Comment: . . . or `luatex`

Comment: @DG' or xetex or ptex yes, basically anything except "tex" :-)